# Magento image resize align top

Tags: magento, image-resizing

Whenever I upload an image, the image has to resize in the lists page. Right now the images are resizing perfectly and generating new resized images with the mentioned dimentions. The proble I am getting when the image is not of proper proportion. Here the image is aligned vertically and horizontally center leaving white space on the top and bottom. I want it to align on the top center. This is not a CSS issue as a new resized image is generated.

Below is the code which I am using now.

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(160,220); ?>" width="160" height="220" />
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this.

Comment: You could just remove the frame entirely which would give you the flexibility to place the image more freely. Add the keepFrame(false) method call prior to calling the resize() method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution for your problem is to have an adaptive resize for your catalog images.

I've done some research and I've found [this extension](https://github.com/roomine/AdaptiveResize).

Please let me know if it solves your problem.

Thanks!